# How to integrate oauth for react front end and node back end?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, oauth-2.0, hapi.js

I am using React as Front end. and i used `react-google-login` and `react-facebook-login` for login with Google and Facebook.

It gives me `accesstoken` in front end.

I passed this `accesstoken` to backend (I am using Node with hapi).

But in backend, how can I get the `userDetails` from Google or Facebook using the `accesstoken` and pass refresh token to get new `accesstoken`?

### Update:

OK There is Three steps in google oauth2 process .

1. take authorization code
2. Exchange authorization code to get access token
3. pass access token to get user info

when i decouple front end and back end . In these three steps what are all i should do in front end and in back-end.
in security aspects ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> when i decouple front end and back end . In these three steps what are all i should do in front end and in back-end. in security aspects ?

In the front-end:
you should get the authorization code and pass the authorization code to the back-end.

In the back-end:
Exchange authorization code + secret to access token/refresh token (the secret is never exposed to the client).
Use the access token to consume endpoints like `get user info` and pass the information back to the front-end.

This is authorization code flow which is recommended.

If you don't have a server you can do Implicit flow which means you don't have a secret so no refresh token. and you get the access token directly in the client - this is less secure.

Comment: Thank you Boaz i done it exactly as you said !! Thank you once again

Comment: I done it google. can i do the same steps for Facebook. i am using react-facebook-login it did't returns authorization code instead it gives full object. Can you help  me ?

Comment: Facebook doing things a bit different from the classic OAuth 2.0. They recommend Facebook Login for short-lived access token using their SDK which is Implicit flow. you can either [exchange him for long lived](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing#exchanging-short-lived-tokens-for-long-lived-tokens) in the server using the secret (keep the secret in the back-end). Or doing something very similar to Google - [authorization code flow in facebbok](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/)

Comment: And how these packages get the userDetails as i did't pass the client_secret to this component props . i only pass client_id.

Comment: you have an access token that you add to the request when you call Facebook Graph API for user details

Comment: Any how Finally i implemented both google and facebook oauth thank you so much

Comment: I implemented this two for signup.  for login also the same steps followed i think . but the popup window comes for few seconds when i already logined in google and already autherized the app. so how to avoid this popup screen in login ?

Comment: If the backend is stateless (e.g. Lambda functions that form an api for the business logic), where should the access_token / refresh_tokens be stored once they are retrieved? Fetching a new token for every single API request doesn't make sense, so presumably you'd have to send them back to the frontend and store them there. But is it right to do that, given that the authorization flow seems to be all about having access_tokens on backend and not getting them in the frontend?

Comment: You can return the access token to the client but what's the point? you want to store them as cookies or local storage? what happen when they expire? (can happen often). Don't return the refresh token to the client. You can store the refresh token in a DB and fetch if they already exists in your lambda.